# Reading and processing data from an S3 stream

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3

I’d like to read data from a large file (order of gbs) in S3 and process it on-the-fly (as opposed to loading the entire file in memory or caching it locally). In some cases, the processing may be lengthy and could potentially “stall” the reading process for several minutes or longer. That is, the connection used to stream the data may become idle for several minutes or more. Below is a contrived example that demonstrates this:

```java
InputStream readStream = s3Client.getObject(GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketLocation).key(fileLocation).build());
readStream.readNBytes(100);
Thread.sleep(600000); // Wait for 10 mins
readStream.readAllBytes(); // Throws SocketException
```

In this example, the second read attempt will throw a `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` error.

I’ve made several attempts to configure the HttpClient to keep the connection open, including the following configuration:

```java
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder()
            .httpClient(
                ApacheHttpClient.builder()
                    .maxConnections(100)
                    .tcpKeepAlive(Boolean.TRUE)
                    .connectionTimeToLive(Duration.ofHours(1))
                    .connectionMaxIdleTime(Duration.ofHours(1))
                    .socketTimeout(Duration.ofHours(1))
                    .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofHours(1))
                    .build())
           .region(region)
           .credentialsProvider(awsCredentials)
           .build();
```

Unfortunately, none of these settings seem to have any impact in resolving this particular problem. Is there anything else I’m missing here? Or is this design inherently flawed?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there's no documented timeout, but I would expect an active server-side timeout to prevent denial of service attacks (ie, your client-side settings have no effect). If you Google you'll see that other people have run into the same situation (although most of them appear to have problems on upload). You could work-around by doing ranged requests. Wrap those in a custom `InputStream` that retrieves X megabytes as-needed, and your code shouldn't have to change.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using the Amazon S3 Transfer Manager to work with larger Amazon S3 objects over the standard client. The client object is **[S3TransferManager](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/transfer/s3/S3TransferManager.html)**.

The Amazon S3 Transfer Manager is an open source, high level file transfer utility for the AWS SDK for Java 2.x. Use it to transfer files and directories to and from Amazon S3.

See the documentation, including examples, in the ***AWS SDK Java V2 Developer Guide***.

[Amazon S3 Transfer Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/transfer-manager.html)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. However, I was trying to stream the file instead of downloading the file. I am not sure if I understand S3TransferManager correctly. Does S3TransferManager also support streaming?

Comment: See https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/async/AsyncResponseTransformer.html